# Creating large arrays

Tags: java

For one of the tests, i need to create arrays of around 300K size. I was looking at some of the ways of doing it.
My approach to this is a little crude. Create an array and add large number of integer(BigInteger) elements in it.

Is there some better way of doing this?

Comment: Does the array itself need to be 300k? or the total size of the contents referenced in the array need to be 300k?

Comment: In what way is the array supposed to be large? Large memory footprint? Or just lots of elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know, for example, that an int is 4 bytes long, why not use that information to allocate 300KB?  I.e. 300KB / 4bytes = ~75,000 ints.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit imprecise...

```
byte[] a = new byte[300000];
```

will trivially create an array of about 300k size. What is your question?